# Should I use AWS RDS for EC2 MYSQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Let's say I've got 100,000 visitors per day and multiple EC2 instances running with load balancers to balance the traffic between the instances.

Would it be wise to have all the EC2 instances connect to the same RDS MySQL database? We're talking about 100K visitors here and let's say that number has the potential to grow. The MySQL database isn't any larger than 10 tables with a maximum of 1K rows in each.

I guess the alternative is to have duplications of the database in each of the ec2 instances, but that really isn't feasible as it would need to be re-duplicated each time there was a change. Thoughts, considerations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If you have multiple application servers, you would most likely want a single database that they work with, so as to keep all data for the application in a single place.  I guess there could be some exceptions, like if the database was read only and you didn't want overhead of remote network call.

Comment: Do you think a medium db instance can handle requests from, say, 5 servers that receive 100K per day traffic per day collectively? Suppose each visitor makes 50 queries ... can a medium instance handle that? There really aren't any resources for estimating resource usage based on things like traffic/# of queries.

Comment: @ChrisScott That would be really hard to say without knowing a profile of the queries the application makes. The hardware requirements could vary widely depending on your schema and DB access patterns.  It doesn't sound like your DB would be memory intensive with the table sizes you mention, so medium or maybe even small might be a good place to start. You should determine what sort of resources you DB's currently use as a starting place - how much memory is used? Are you able to load all your indexes into that memory (which is what you want)? Ultimately, you will really need to load test.

Comment: Hi Mike, I figured the inevitable answer to this was "it depends." But I just wanted to know if it was at least *conceivable* that a small/medium db instance could process the requests for 100K daily visitors if the requests were small and everything was optimized. Based on your comment, it is conceivable and a good place to start. Thanks!